# Require user to call a method eventually

Tags: scala

Assume I have a class like this:

```
case class Test(pars: Seq[Int] = Seq()) {
  def require(p: Int) = copy(pars = p +: pars)

  def execute() = {assert(???)}
}
```

It is intended to be used like this:

```
Test().require(1).require(2).execute()
```

I am using this in tests. Sometimes it happens I forget to call `execute()` which makes the test to pass, as the testing code is not executed at all.

Would it be possible to create a check to notify me about this? I have tried an implicit conversion to unit, but it was not applied, default compiler one is used:

```
implicit def toUnit(setup: Test): Unit = setup.execute() // or ???
```

It is not a big issue, I can solve it by being more careful, but having a compiler (or even runtime) to warn me would make it easier. The actual way to how create or execute the test is not important and can be changed, it does not have to be a case class and its member.

Comment: So, if you keep chaining methods how do you know that it is time to validate? What if I write this in 2 separate lines?

Comment: I would like to be warned anytime `Test` value is discarded. Assigning it to a variable is OK, but discarding silently is not.

Comment: But if you `copy` the previous instance of `Test` is discarded.

Comment: @Jasper-M Technically you are correct. It is however not discarded without being used first. I think my idea about conversion to `Unit` is sound - I want to be warned when `Test` is converted to `Unit`. I guess this is not possible, perhaps there is some other way to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution might be refactoring to something along these lines:

```
sealed abstract class Test private (pars: Seq[Int] = Seq()) {
  def require(p: Int): Test = new Test.Impl(pars = p +: pars)
  private def execute(): Unit = println("Execute!")
}
object Test {
  def apply(f: Test => Test) = f(new Test.Impl()).execute()

  private class Impl(pars: Seq[Int] = Seq()) extends Test(pars)
}

Test {
  _.require(1).require(2)
}
```

The idea of the solution is to hide the `Test` constructor, so that the one able to call it can guarantee `execute` is always paired with it.

Comment: I took a liberty to clean it up - I find your solution excellent. If you disagree with my changes, just revert them. If you still want to add some explanation, please do so. The code as it is now compiles fine.

Comment: If you leave off the abstract, you can still call `Test()`.

Comment: You are correct. Reverted that, abstract needs to stay. I have simplified some other stuff.

Comment: Yes I can agree with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for all (non-`Unit`) types by using the `-Ywarn-value-discard` compiler option. If you want to limit it to `Test`, this should be doable with [Wart Remover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover).

Comment: This is definitely nice. Unfortunately when applied to my tests, I have been forced to realize ScalaTest test signature (at least for FunSuite or FlatSpec) is `testFun : => scala.Any`, therefore the value is discarded somewhere in the test framework, and I get no warning. :(

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I came with a solution which allows me to write the execute before the test setup instead of after it, this way it is easier for me not to forget:

```
object execute {
  def --(setup: Test) = setup.execute()
}

execute -- Test().require(1)
```